# Firebase fails to send password reset email from console

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

The *existing user* has trouble signing in and wants to reset the password. She doesn’t receive any reset password emails. We also tried to send the reset email through `Firebase Console` but no luck - no emails got delivered.

Is there any way to set a password manually through `Firebase console` or any other workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there are any issues with sending emails at the moment, as that would typically be showing on the [Firebase status page](https://status.firebase.google.com/). In that case such problems are almost always caused by the messages being marked as span either by the user's email client, or (less common) by the mail server of their provider.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the user's password through Firebase's Admin SDKs. These SDKs run with administrative privileges, so should only be run in a trusted environment such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions.

This is an example of setting a user's password with Node.js:

```
admin.auth().updateUser(uid, { password: "newPassword" })
```

For more samples (including in other supported languages), see the [documentation on updating a user profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user).

Answer (score 1):

1. Firebase Admin SDK sounds like a good option
2. Check SMTP settings in the reset mail template
3. De-hash password manually :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Issue got resolved. SendGrid (service that Firebase uses to send emails) had some maintenance during 8 hours in Asia region (my user is from Asia region) that's why it was working for me and not working for her.

Check SendGrid status URL: http://status.sendgrid.com

Thanks for all your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You can set a user's password with the `updatePassword` method and send "SOME-SECURE-PASSWORD" :)

For example:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String newPassword = "SOME-SECURE-PASSWORD";

user.updatePassword(newPassword)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "User password updated.");
                }
            }
        });
```

[Documentation is here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#send_a_password_reset_email)

Comment: Great, thanks for sharing that! Unfortunately current user is nil because user is not signed in and unable to because she doesn’t remember her password. + it would be a code change and new release, isn’t it?

Comment: Maybe better for user  sign in via social networks as facebook, Google and etc( if it is implemented). Or user have to  check spam folder and filter settings in her mailbox.

Comment: It is implemented but initial account was created via email and password. There is nothing in spam folder unfortunately.